# How to make a strong mug of instant Coffee?

Tags: coffee

I am not an avid coffee drinker.

Yesterday, I tried [Bru Gold coffee](http://www.brucoffee.in/OurCoffees.aspx) brand. I mixed one teaspoon milk with 1 teaspoon coffee and added the remaining 200ml hot milk premixed with 2 teaspoons of sugar.

The result wasn't great. The coffee was NOT strong nor did it contain any froth.

I want strong, not bitter coffee.
How do I know how much coffee to add to how much milk?
Secondly, do I have to mix coffee in whole milk and then boil the whole thing like it is done for tea?
Does the amount of time I spend in mixing coffee with milk also have an effect on the outcome?

Comment: "Did not contain any froth" - do you expect a "crema" from instant coffee? I don't think there is a way to get it (although I admit I don't have that much knowledge in coffee). Your question reads as if you expect something espresso-like.

Comment: Turkish Coffee: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_coffee

Comment: @rumtscho I don't know anything about coffee. I had seen in tv ads about the froth. What should I expect from this coffee?

Comment: @TheRebelAquarius "Crema" is a light-colored foam layer which builds on top of espresso, and many people like it. Espresso is also stronger than normal coffee. For both, you need an espresso machine and real coffee beans. Different coffee brewing methods produce different types of coffee. Espresso is the hardest to make at home. Instant coffee is easy, but has bad reputation taste-wise, so don't expect to get coffee shop quality with it.

Comment: As pointed out, use real coffee in a coffee maker. but you don't have to buy an expensive coffee machine, just a single cup stove-top pot is great. the freshness of the beans and when they were ground can also make quite a difference.

Comment: If you're looking into a cheap coffee making process: you can get an Aeropress for $30. Look into it, it's cheap, easy and allows you to make a strong coffee that will taste great.

Comment: Did this product come with instructions to use only milk? I have *never* heard of any coffee, instant or otherwise, being made that way. It sounds disgusting, and no wonder it didn't taste strong - you were drinking milk! Even a latte has to be mixed with espresso, which is *very* strong/concentrated coffee on its own. Instant coffee is also specifically made to dissolve, so I can't think how it would ever give you "froth", unless maybe you whip the milk first - but then the froth is entirely from the milk, not the coffee.

Comment: The milk-only thing made me jump back a little as I read it. I LOVE drinking milk straight but I don't let that stuff near my coffee.

Answer (score 1):

What is too bitter is likely to be primarily opinion-based. That said, when I make instant coffee, I usually use one teaspoon per 200-250 ml of water - not milk. The result is a nice, even cup of coffee, which is not what I would characterize as strong. If I want strong coffee, I will use as much as four teaspoons to the same amount of water.

The milk will have a mellowing effect on the end result. In combination with the sugar, it has been my experience that the milk masks the bitter taste of coffee that many people do not enjoy.

I would recommend playing around with how much coffee you use. Once you get the strength you want, you can add or remove sugar to reduce the bitterness.

Answer (score 0):

To make froth in coffee.. Take 1 teaspoon of instant coffee and sugar to taste.. add a teaspoon of boiling water to this. Mix them by whisking and beating.. you can see the mixture turn to froth.. now add 1 cup of hot milk to this.. Tasty frothy coffee is ready.. fir a strong coffee add little more coffee..

Comment: Good idea. You can use an immersion blender to accomplish similar results.